# HTTP/HTTPS routing according to URL

Tags: router, http, https, internal-dns

Hy everyone,
I'm not a networking newbie, but a 'stackoverflow' newbie for sure, so I apologize in advice if i screwed-up category or group, but there seems that all this stuff is based on tags.

I have the following question that crossed my mind as I'm expanding my test server.

- I worked with WWW balancing (Having different public IPs referred to the same domain)
- I worked with internal hardware balancers (with traffic comming from same public IP and a single url www.example.com)

But this morning I got two new machines from a friend, and I decided that will keep them for my selve expanding my testing server from 1 to 3 units.

Now , as I have few domains, a public static IP and a fast connection (FTTH) that is enough. I was wonderding to have someones opinion, that may allready did it and therefore figured out the best solution.My domains refer all to the same IP and my routher has just a DMZ server option that forward traffic to a single LAN IP.

Now which are the solutions (rather hardware) that allow me to split ingoing HTTP/HTTPS request according their URL?

**www.example.com -> server01 [10.10.0.1]**

**ftp.example.com -> server02 [10.10.0.2]**

Comment: I must be missing something in your question because you'd need nothing other than the most basic of DNS entries to handle your example.  An entry for www pointing at one IP, another entry for ftp pointing at the other IP.

Comment: I mean, both server IPs are not public as i have just a single internet connection and a public IP. So in WWW both domains refer to my home IP, and then I'm asking about any cind of hardware solution that identify the URL and divide recquests on the INTERNAL LAN IPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on hardware, I'd suggest Cisco ACE or something similair.

But it's an incredible waste of money. For the fraction of Cisco's junk's cost (and yes, Cisco ACE is junk), you can deploy a Linux server running Apache, Nginx, Varnish or whatever, that will do everything you need and more.

Comment: I'm not wonderng to use a deployed server to do so, as throughput will be really affected by this single unit. Which is your suggested configuration. Making an inner DNS or using the server as junk?

Comment: What you're talking about is not DNS-related. Instead, it's proxy: the server  (or Cisco ACE) will sit on the public IP, do HTTP/HTTPS and proxy the requests to the two servers behind it. Depending on the specific requirements and with correct configuration you can have multiple virtual hosts share the same IP and taliking to the proper servers behind it. It's all very besic HTTP 1.1 stuff, really.

Comment: I know that is basic stuff, and i was allready virtualizing multiple hosts. Let's say that my question was more related to traffic efficient solution. As I got a hub and requests were send to both servers, then i just configured one of servers to refuse some URL, I did it many years ago, i do not remember exact configuration and test results, but was not very efficient! As traffic was allways bothering both servers.

Answer (score 0):

PFSense can do it. There's no point in buying some kind of appliance to do it, it's mostly the same thing and way cheaper. Linux could do it too, the same way.

[Having two subdomains on one public IP addres behind pFsense router](https://serverfault.com/questions/542416/having-two-subdomains-on-one-public-ip-addres-behind-pfsense-router)